# Store a variable in a conversation in iMessage Apps

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I'm completly new to developing iMessage Apps.

I would like to store a shared variable (let's say an Int) to a conversation. The Use case could be an incrementing integer, that is incremented every time a message is send from any participant in the conversation.

**Is this posible?**

I have searched for this this without any luck.

Comment: Not sure about your task, But in my case  "didStartSending" method is calling always when i am sending message.

Comment: I am new in this too. However, I believe you can keep track by sending the variable using `NSURLComponent`. Based on my research so far, most of the turn based game app use that to keep track of the game state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can attach shared variable in URL .**

//Insert the URL when user send the Message .

> ```
>    let message = MSMessage()
>     message.layout = layout
>     message.url = URL(string: "application/sharedVariable=X")
>     self.activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: { (error) in
>         print("error")
>     })
> ```

You can extract above shared Variable from above URL .

> ```
>   let url = "http://application/sharedVariable=X" 
>   let queryItems = URLComponents(string: url)?.queryItems
>   let sharedValue = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "sharedVariable"}).first          
>   print(sharedValue?.value)
> ```

**If you do not want anyone to know the shared Variable then you can encrypt while sending.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iMessageDataKit](https://github.com/svtek/iMessageDataKit) library. It's a tiny, useful `MSMessage` extension for setting/getting `Int`, `Bool`, `Float`, `Double`, `String` and `Array` values for keys.

It makes setting and getting data really easy like:

```
let message: MSMessage = MSMessage()

message.md.set(value: 1, forKey: "messageCount")

print(message.md.integer(forKey: "messageCount")!)
```

*(Disclaimer: I'm the author of `iMessageDataKit`)*